# Automatically fill fields on an Access form

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

What is the simplest way for me to get MS Access 2007 to autofill a form based on the entry added in the first field?

I currently have 4 tables.... Customers, Parts, Order Header, and Order Lines. I have created a form for the order header table with a subform for the orderlines.

ideally what i want is that when i add the customer number into the order header form, it autofills the rest of the form with the customer name and details etc etc....

and same principle... when i add the product number to the order lines form, it autofills the Order ID and part description and sales price, taking the info from the parts table and order header table.....

Now i know for the majority of you guys this is bread and butter, but please explain in the simplest form possible... i am by no means 100% computer literate.

Comment: Firstly, thanks for your reponse....No they are stored in the customer table.... the order header table is for the the initial set up of a customer order...then the order line subform will be used to input the order lines....which should take parts from the parts table.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example from a form I use.  It uses Dlookup from a table in the same .mdb file.  You enter a part number and then everything else populates after you hit tab:

```
Private Sub Item_Number_AfterUpdate()
    PopulateFields
End Sub

Private Sub PopulateFields()
''''PopulateFields takes the Item Number to fill in all the remaining fields with regards to that Item
    Me.Full_Desc = RTrim(DLookup("ITEMDESC", "GP_Parts_List_Import", "ITEMNMBR = '" & Me.Item_Number & "'"))
    Me.Item_Type = RTrim(DLookup("ITEMTYPE", "GP_Parts_List_Import", "ITEMNMBR = '" & Me.Item_Number & "'"))
    Me.General_Desc = RTrim(DLookup("ITMGEDSC", "GP_Parts_List_Import", "ITEMNMBR = '" & Me.Item_Number & "'"))
    Me.Current_Cost = RTrim(DLookup("CURRCOST", "GP_Parts_List_Import", "ITEMNMBR = '" & Me.Item_Number & "'"))
    Me.Item_Class_Code = RTrim(DLookup("ITMCLSCD", "GP_Parts_List_Import", "ITEMNMBR = '" & Me.Item_Number & "'"))
End Sub
```

**UPDATE**

To get to the VBA part of your application, you press F11 or right click on the control you want triggering the code.  After right click, select 'Build Event' and then choose 'Code Builder' to open the VBA Editor window.  [image: VBA Editor]

The drop down on the left will give you every control you can choose from in that form, and the drop down on the right will give you every event that control has available.  So when my text box `Item_Number` is filled and a user moves on, `AfterUpdate` is triggered and runs the function `PopulateFields`.

You'll need to replace the text boxes and table names obviously, and this is only one way to do it.  But hope this helps.

Comment: Where would i input this??? is there anywhere in the design view for the table i can add a dlookup or is it only available in the query section. thanks for your help so far.

Comment: Well im getting somewhere thanks.... so instead of that code.... would this work as a means of simple coding?? Private Sub Customer_AfterUpdate() CustomerName = Customer.Column(2) End Sub If so.... can you explain the purpose of 'column(2) please....

Comment: Of course, but you need to make sure you reference the fields in the form with `Me.CustomerName = Me.Customer.Column(2)`.